# How to access all elements from dictionary - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, react-class-based-component

API returns parents and their children in a dictionary.

// Dictionary with string as its key(parent) and list of strings(children) as its value as below:

```
        { "A": ["AQ11"], "B": [], "C": ["CN22", "CL33"] }
```

I have two questions, Have I set my data structure correct to hold the API values (does it add all parents and children to dictionary).

And how do I iterate thru all elements in the dictionary. Thanks.

Below is my state:

```
    this.state = {
      items:
          {
                parentItemNo: "",
                childItemNo: [],              
          }
```

```
  return (
        <div>                      
            {this.state.items.parentItemNo},
            {this.state.items.childItemNo[1]}
        </div>
     )
```

Above returns only the last element of the dictionary -> C, CL33.

I have changed my data structure now as below as advised.

```
items:
      [{
            parentItemNo: "",
            childItemNo: [],              
      }]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you are saving an object that has repeated keys. The key 'parentItemNo' is being saved with 3 different values and the first values are being overriden with the latest values. You should (if it's within your possibilities) save an array of objects like this:

```
items: [
    { parentItemNo: "A", childItemNo: ["AQ11"] },
    { parentItemNo: "B", childItemNo: [] },
    { parentItemNo: "C", childItemNo: ["CN22", "CL33"] }
]
```

and then you can access the different objects (or dictionaries) like this:

```
    items[0].parentItemNo //returns "A"
    items[2].childItemNo //return ["CN22", "CL33"]
```

Comment: I managed to get key value pair. [{"Key":"A","Value":["AQ11"]},{"Key":"B","Value":[]},{"Key":"C","Value":["CN22", "CL33"]}]. May I know how do I access this with a data structure like this ->  items:
         [{
                parentItemNo: "",
                childItemNo: []          
          }]

Comment: If what you want is to find an object inside the array you could use the following:
`items.find(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.key === 1)`
use the array method 'find' and compare values. Here we a going through every element of the array (in this case we are naming them 'keyValuePair' and then filtering them by their 'key' property. You could do it with de 'value' property as well, or both of them.

Comment: Because now you are using an array, you could push new objects into this array like this:
`.then((responseData) => {                           
                        let items= [...this.state.items];
                        response.data.forEach(data =>
                            items.push({
                            childItemNo= data.value;
                            parentItemNo= data.key;
                            })                           
                            this.setState({items});
                        }`
We are pushing new objects to the array.

Comment: Thank you, It says unexpected token pointing childItemNo and parentItemNo, when I try the above code

Comment: what kind of Object comes in responseData? could you show me?

Comment: responseData -> [ {Key:"A",Value:["AQ11"]}, {Key:"B",Value:[]}, {Key:"C",Value:["CN22", "CL33"]} ]. If I try console.log(responseData[2]), it gives -> {Key:"C",Value:["CN22", "CL33"]}. But not able to get key and value separately.

Comment: My mistake, using capital V and K as above for value and key solved the issue.